# Android Locale country&variant issue

Tags: android

I am facing a problem with country&variant - the problem boiled down to the following code:

```
for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
    if (!locale.getCountry().isEmpty())
        System.out.println(" country: " + locale.getCountry());
    if (!locale.getVariant().isEmpty())
        System.out.println(" variant: " + locale.getVariant());
    System.out.println("------");
}
```

produces output like:

```
I/System.out( 7651):  country: NG
I/System.out( 7651): ------
I/System.out( 7651): ------
I/System.out( 7651):  country: HANS
I/System.out( 7651): ------
I/System.out( 7651):  country: HANS
I/System.out( 7651):  variant: CN
I/System.out( 7651): ------
I/System.out( 7651):  country: HANS
I/System.out( 7651):  variant: HK
I/System.out( 7651): ------
I/System.out( 7651):  country: HANS
I/System.out( 7651):  variant: MO
I/System.out( 7651): ------
I/System.out( 7651):  country: HANS
I/System.out( 7651):  variant: SG
I/System.out( 7651): ------
I/System.out( 7651):  country: HANT
I/System.out( 7651): ------
I/System.out( 7651):  country: HANT
I/System.out( 7651):  variant: HK
I/System.out( 7651): ------
I/System.out( 7651):  country: HANT
I/System.out( 7651):  variant: MO
I/System.out( 7651): ------
I/System.out( 7651):  country: HANT
I/System.out( 7651):  variant: TW
I/System.out( 7651): ------
I/System.out( 7651): ------
I/System.out( 7651):  country: ZA
I/System.out( 7651): ------
```

for me this looks wrong - but I found no corresponding bug and I cannot believe that I am the first to stumble uppon this.

Comment: I agree it looks wrong, but, as per doc `This class' constructors do no error checking. You can create a Locale for languages and countries that don't exist, and you can create instances for combinations that don't exist (such as "de_US" for "German as spoken in the US").` That means that a `new Locale("", "", "");` can be made by anyone. The question is, which device is doing that? Plus, what is your question?

Comment: OK I can create invalid locales - this is OK - but I expect the locales that the system gives me as available locales should be valid - otherwise this looks like a bug to me. My question is if this is a bug or if I understood something wrong.

Comment: It's a bug. OEMs do all type of sh*t with their devices. Samsung in special loves making developers life a nightmare. On the app I work at (average of 100K active users per day) have lots of code with the comment `// handle with crappy Samsung`. It's just how it is.

Comment: I know ( I am developing android apps since 1.6 ) - but this output was from some nexus ..